# Firebase createdAt - timestamp vs date

Tags: swift, firebase

Trying to sort snapshot array by createdAt.  Difficulty since google changed from Date format to TimeStamp

I have tried to convert timestamp to date using Timestamp.dateValue()

I used this which worked when they were using Date

```
 self.tableData = self.tableData.sorted(by: { 
 $0["createdAt"] as! Date > $1["createdAt"] as! Date })
```

I tried to use this with Timestamp since you cant sort directly on Timestamp - I can not get it to work or have proper syntax...

```
   self.tableData =  self.tableData.sorted(by: {
       $0["createdAt"] as Timestamp.dateValue() as! Date >
       $1["createdAt"] as Timestamp.dateValue() as! Date })
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Any idea why google changed from Date to Timestamp?  It makes sorting harder.  I know you can sort during the request, but I need to sort following the database request.

Comment: Does the Timestamp compare method help you at all?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp#compare_:

Comment: Referencing *createdAt* is a bit vague without understanding what specifically you're storing in that field.  Also, can you include the code of how that document/field is being read and stored in your array?

Comment: The reason? *NSDate is implemented as a double which loses precision and causes unexpected behavior when using a timestamp from a snapshot as a part of a subsequent query.* Also, see [areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/FirestoreSettings#/c:objc(cs)FIRFirestoreSettings(py)timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled) because it can be turned off to restore prior behavior noting that you should be migrating to the newer Timestamp format.

Answer (score 1):

> I did it as below:-

- While mapping data, map it as date type variable:-

  ```
  let createdAt : Date? = snapshotValue["createdAt"] as? Date
  ```
- And then I sort the array as below:-

  ```
  let currentArr = commentsArray.sorted(by: {
          $0.createdAt!.compare($1.createdAt!) == .orderedDescending
      })
  ```

OR

you can fetch sorted data directly as shown below:-

```
    Firestore.firestore().collection(“samples”).order(by: "createdAt", descending: true).whereField(“sampleId”, isEqualTo: sampleId).addSnapshotListener({ (querySnapSHot, error) in })
```

Comment: This used to work but, Google currently is now using Timestamp instead of date for createdAt

Comment: You can store value as timestamp in firebase. This is the code after fetching timestamp value.

Comment: Got it.  I was hoping to not have to modify my db and sort directly on the timestamp values as provided in the snapshot.

Comment: Yes, you do not need to change your database unless you store your "createdAt" value as TimeStamp.

Comment: Google is changing this.  Firestore moving to timestamps in Firebase functions.  Reference:  https://codeday.me/en/qa/20190305/1949.html

Comment: Thanks but for specific reasons I have to sort post db fetch.  The swift array object sort functions will sort on Date but don't seem to support sort on Timestamp - unfortunately!

Comment: Thats why I converted timestamp to date format after fetching the data from Firestore. Why don't you try at least once as in the snapshot?